# Select option from array with name and selected value in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, select, selected

In my project i'm using AngularJS for a template that receive multiple data from array.

The json array have this format:

{"restaurant": {
    "Restaurant": {
      "id": "1",
      "money": "3"
    }}}

the variable is {{restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money}}

I need to have the result described below:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Meno di 15 euro</option>
    <option value="2">15-25 euro</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">25-45 euro</option>
    <option value="4">45-65 euro</option>
    <option value="5">Più di 65 euro</option>
</select>
```

where the **option value="3"** is **"selected"** because is the value extracted from the array.

Thank you for your support.

Edit: this is my

```
<select>
    <option value="1" ng-selected="{{{true: 'selected', false: ''}[restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == 1]}}">Meno di 15 euro</option>
    <option value="2" ng-selected="{{{true: 'selected', false: ''}[restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == 2]}}">15-25 euro</option>
    <option value="3" ng-selected="{{{true: 'selected', false: ''}[restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == 3]}}">25-45 euro</option>
    <option value="4" ng-selected="{{{true: 'selected', false: ''}[restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == 4]}}">45-65 euro</option>
    <option value="5" ng-selected="{{{true: 'selected', false: ''}[restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == 5]}}">Più di 65 euro</option>
</select>
```

This code product a line like this

```
<select>
    <option ng-selected="" value="1">Meno di 15 euro</option>
    <option ng-selected="" value="2">15-25 euro</option>
    <option ng-selected="selected" value="3">25-45 euro</option>
    <option ng-selected="" value="4">45-65 euro</option>
    <option ng-selected="" value="5">Più di 65 euro</option>
</select>
```

but in the browser, the focus is on the first option (value="1")

Edit 2:

This is my http://jsfiddle.net/oibaf80/5D94S/

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: @oibaf80 do you meany by something like this `{ "restaurant": [{ ..., "money": "3", ... }], ...}`

Comment: Can you make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing your problem? The expression you pass into ng-selected should evaluate to true or false btw.

Comment: I've added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use Ng-option instead of option. and provide ng-model to select default value.. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select see example given at this page..

Answer (score 0):

Your select can be like -

```
<select class="smallPageSizeInput" ng-model="selectedAmount" ng-options="selectedAmount for selectedAmount in ['Meno di 15 euro', '15-25 euro', '25-45 euro', '45-65 euro', 'Più di 65 euro']" ng-init="selectedAmount=userSelectedAmount"></select>
```

Below is a sample of your controller code.

```
var moneyMapping = {'1': 'Meno di 15 euro', '2' : '15-25 euro', '3' : '25-45 euro', '4' : '45-65 euro', '5' : 'Più di 65 euro'};

var resolvedUserObj = {"restaurant": { "Restaurant": { "id": "1", "money": "3" }}};

$scope.userSelectedAmount =  moneyMapping[resolvedUserObj.restaurant.Restaurant.money];
```

You would need to change "resolvedUserObj" to get it from the array or wherever else you get it from.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I can't modify the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you don't need to manually manage which elements are selected, etc.  When you set the data, it will automatically be reflected in the HTML UI.

However, based on your comments, it looks like you want to do something a very specific way in the HTML. Therefore, you can use the following:

The HTML would be:

```
    <select>
        <option value="1" ng-selected="restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == '1'">Meno di 15 euro</option>
        <option value="2" ng-selected="restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == '2'">15-25 euro</option>
        <option value="3" ng-selected="restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == '3'">25-45 euro</option>
        <option value="4" ng-selected="restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == '4'">45-65 euro</option>
        <option value="5" ng-selected="restaurant.restaurant.Restaurant.money == '5'">Più di 65 euro</option>
    </select>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5D94S/17/

Comment: Sorry, I can't modify the controller.

Comment: Ok. That's interesting. In any case, I updated the solution to not change the controller code

Comment: Had a bug previously, Angular doesn't like carriage returns in the ng-options.  Should work now along with the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5D94S/13/)

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answers but the problem is that from the controller, I receive only the ID that is selected, nor the list and the names. The names ('Meno di 15 euro', ecc...) are wired in html. My desire is to be able to set to 'selected="selected"' the option with the same ID (3) that I receive from controller.

Comment: OK. Updated the solution to do it the way you were thinking of doing it.  Not ideal if you're using Angular, but it would work.